# How to send JSON data using axios?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, axios

I have created a dynamic form using vuejs

```
<form class="w-2/4">
      <h1>Create New Course</h1>
                    <div>
                        <label class="block mt-4">
                            <span class="text-gray-700">Grade</span>
                            <select class="form-select mt-1 block" v-model="form.grade">
                            <option v-for="index in ['4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'Others']" :value="index">{{ index }}</option>
                            </select>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div class="flex justify-between">
                            <h1 class="p-2">Headings</h1>
                            <button class="bg-green-300 p-2 rounded-xl" @click="addHeading" type="button">Add heading</button>
                        </div>
                        <div v-for='(head, h_index) in form.headings'>
                            <div class="flex gap-8">
                                <label class="block" for="h_id">
                                    <span class="text-gray-700">H_Id</span>
                                    <input class="form-input mt-1 block p-2 outine-black border-2 border-black" id="h_id" type="h_id" value="head.h_id" v-model="head.h_id">
                                </label>
                                <label class="block">
                                    <span class="text-gray-700">Heading</span>
                                    <input class="form-input mt-1 block p-2 outine-black border-2 border-black" v-model="head.heading">
                                </label>
                                <label class="block">
                                    <span class="text-gray-700">Description</span>
                                    <textarea class="form-textarea mt-1 block p-4 outine-black border-2 border-black" rows="1" v-model="head.description"></textarea>
                                </label>
                                <label class="block mt-4">
                                    <span class="text-gray-700">Type</span>
                                    <select class="form-select mt-1 block" v-model="head.type">
                                    <option v-for="type in ['Free', 'Premium']" :value="type">{{ type }}</option>
                                    </select>
                                </label>
                                <div>
                                    <button class="bg-red-300 m-8 p-2 rounded-xl" type="button" @click="deleteHeading(h_index)"><span>Delete heading</span></button>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <button class="bg-green-300 m-8 p-2 rounded-xl" type="button" @click="addSubHeading(h_index)"><span>Add Subheading</span></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ml-12" v-for='(sub, s_index) in head.subheadings'>
                                <div class="flex gap-8">
                                    <label class="block">
                                        <span class="text-gray-700">S_Id</span>
                                        <input class="form-input mt-1 block p-2 outine-black border-2 border-black" v-model="sub.s_id">
                                    </label>
                                    <label class="block">
                                        <span class="text-gray-700">Title</span>
                                        <input class="form-input mt-1 block p-2 outine-black border-2 border-black" v-model="sub.title">
                                    </label>
                                    <label class="block">
                                        <span class="text-gray-700">Description</span>
                                        <textarea class="form-textarea mt-1 block p-4 outine-black border-2 border-black" rows="1" v-model="sub.description"></textarea>
                                    </label>
                                    <div>
                                        <button class="bg-red-300 m-8 p-2 rounded-xl" type="button" @click="deleteSubHeading(h_index, s_index)"><span>Delete Subheading</span></button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <button class="bg-green-300 m-8 p-2 rounded-xl" type="button" @click="addtopic(h_index, s_index)"><span>Add Topic</span></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="ml-12" v-for='(topic, t_index) in sub.topics'>
                                    <div class="flex gap-16">
                                        <label class="block">
                                            <span class="text-gray-700">T_Id</span>
                                            <input class="form-input mt-1 block p-2 outine-black border-2 border-black" v-model="topic.id">
                                        </label>
                                        <label class="block">
                                            <span class="text-gray-700">Topic</span>
                                            <input class="form-input mt-1 block p-2 outine-black border-2 border-black" v-model="topic.Subject">
                                        </label>
                                        <label class="block">
                                            <span class="text-gray-700">Description</span>
                                            <textarea class="form-textarea mt-1 block p-4 outine-black border-2 border-black" rows="1" v-model="topic.description"></textarea>
                                        </label>
                                        <div>
                                            <button class="bg-red-300 m-8 p-2 rounded-xl" type="button" @click="deletetopic(h_index, s_index, t_index)"><span>Delete Topic</span></button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <button class="bg-red-300 m-8 p-2 rounded-xl" type="submit" @click="submit"><span>Submit</span></button>
                        </div>
                </form>
```

this is my script code:

```
<script>
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        form: {
            grade: "",
            headings: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addHeading() {      
        this.form.headings.push({h_id:'',heading:'',description:'',type:"",subheadings:[]})
    },
    deleteHeading(h_index){    
        this.form.headings.splice(h_index,1);             
    },
    addSubHeading(h_index) {
        this.form.headings[h_index].subheadings.push({s_id:'',title:'',description:'', topics:[]})
    },
    deleteSubHeading(h_index, s_index){    
        this.form.headings[h_index].subheadings.splice(s_index,1);             
    },
    addtopic(h_index, s_index) {
        this.form.headings[h_index].subheadings[s_index].topics.push({t_id:'',Subject:'',description:''})
    },
    deletetopic(h_index, s_index, t_index){    
        this.form.headings[h_index].subheadings[s_index].topics.splice(t_index,1);             
    },
    submit:async function(){
        const formData = JSON.stringify(this.form) 
        console.log(formData)
        await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/admin/dashboard/addcourse', formData)
        }
    } 
});

</script>
```

I'm using nodejs as backend, when I click submit button I'm getting like this

`[Object: null prototype] { '{"grade":"","headings":[]}': '' }`

this is my nodejs code:

```
router.post('/dashboard/addcourse', async (req, res, next) => {

    console.log(req.body)

})
```

how to send the form data as JSON?
I want the req.body in JSON format like shown below

```
{"grade":"","headings":[]}
```

I don't know where I'm going wrong, please guide me

Comment: // Bodyparser
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}))

I'm not getting any error in terminal

Comment: It's not working, the same result